# How to cover a method which is placed inside an array

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

In one of my component, I used a dynamic form and for that dynamic form to work, I need to send the form elements as an array from component file. Also, if the form element has a event to be performed, I also need to send the event via array, so that it renders dynamically. Here is the array

```
defineTestForm(): void {
    this.dynamicFormParams = {
      mainFilters: [
        {
          filters: [
            {
              name: 'testDropdown',
              inputType: 'dropdown',
              width: '3',
              label: 'test label',
              placeholder: 'test placeholder',
              required: true,
              validators: [],
              showClear: true,
              showFilter: true,
              options: this.someoptions,
              change: (event, form) => {
                this.somemethod(event.value);
              }
            },
            {
              name: 'testArea',
              inputType: 'textarea',
              width: '4',
              label: 'Test',
              placeholder: '',
              required: false,
              validators: [],
            },
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

While the code is working fine, the code coverage is not. `change` method and `this.somemethod` is not getting covered. How to cover it?

here is the code that I tried. but didn't worked

```
  describe('#defineTestForm', () => {
    it('should cover the method', () => {
      spyOn(component, 'somemethod')
      component.defineTestForm();
      component?.dynamicFormParams?.mainFilters[0]?.filters[0]?.change({ value : 111 } as any, null) // Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined' 
      expect(component.somemethod).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
  })
```

Comment: code looks correct to me, try putting some logs in the calling method and see where it has reached? maybe you need to mock the dynamicFormParams

Comment: This method's only function is to assign an array to dynamicFormParams, how can I mock it? defeats the unit testing right? or I misunderstood, please explain elborately. Thanks for replying :)

Comment: A better approach than "how can I test that function" would be to ask yourself: "What would break if that function was not there? What does the user need to do so that this function is needed?" And then do that in your test.

Comment: // @ts-ignore: Object is possibly 'null'.

Adding this line above `component?.dynamicFormParams?.mainFilters[0]?.filters[0]?.change({ value : 111 } as any, null)` solves the issue and the code is covered. But is there any other way not to suppress the ts errors and still covers the code